# Get Original Sender Email Address using EWS Managed API 2.2

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Does EWS Managed API 2.2 support retrieving email address of original sender?  For example:

userA sends email to userB

userB forwards that email to userC

I monitor userC Inbox using EWS.  Can I retrieve userA email address as the from address of the email I read from userC Inbox (that originated from UserA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how the message has been forwarded eg if they use Outlook,OWA,ActiveSync and click the forward button what you see is what you will get in the Target Mailbox (eg the Sender will be the forwarder). If they have used Rules to forward the message then the redirect rule would maintain the Sender while the forward action would change it.

A few workarounds is you should be able to parse the body the From: header from the body (this is a bit hit and miss though). You should have the InternetMesssageId of the Original message maintained in the In-Reply-To header of the message which could be used to find the original message in the Message Tracking logs which you could then extract the original sender from.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Can you please provide sample code on how to extract the email address?

Comment: Can you be more specific extract it from where ? normally you would use the from address https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.from(v=exchg.80).aspx